# what happens Object class reference variable that refers inherited class during runtime?

Tags: java

```
public class A{}
```

I have created a class with name 'A' and in main class i wrote this statement below:

```
Object m = new A();
```

after compilation time, what happens to variable m ? I mean, won't reference type of m  cast to its actual type which means 'A' ? If so, why i'm not getting any runtime error when i write this statement below :

```
m = new Object();
```

Object class is parent class. So, is it possible to cast child class reference variable to parent class variable ?

I hope i could tell my problem clearly. sorry for my english, thanks for all help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m` is a reference that can point to any `Object` or any subclass of `Object`.  That is why

```
Object m = new A();
```

works.  Note that `m` itself keeps no knowledge of the type of object it actually points to at runtime.  Which is why you ***can't*** do

```
...m.someMethodOfA()...   // Fails at compile time
```

The compiler knows `m` can point to only `Object` instances, and using `m` you can access only members of `Object`, even if the runtime type is something else.

At runtime, as long as `m` still points to an `A` instance, then you can do things like

```
...((A)m).someMethodOfA()...
```

Note it is *you* that knows this and you encode that knowledge by using the down-cast from `Object` to `A`.  So later in the program if your code does:

```
m = new Object();
```

the old reference to an `A` instance is forgotten, but since `m` never knew it originally pointed to an `A`, there's no problem with this assignment.

After this, however, the down-cast to `A`, which was previously valid, will now result in `ClassCastException`.

Comment: i clearly understood because of you, thank you .

Answer (score 0):

> what happens to variable m ?

After `Object m = new A();` is run, `m` stores a reference to the instance of `A` you just created.

There is no casting, casting a variable `x` to a type `T` looks something like this: `(T)x`, and you are not doing that here. There is a *type conversion* from `A` to `Object`, because `Object` and `A` are different types, but nothing (no checks etc) actually needs to be done at runtime, because `Object` is a superclass of `A`, so the conversion always succeeds.

> If so, why i'm not getting any runtime error when i write this statement below :

```
m = new Object();
```

This line stores a reference to an `Object` object in `m`, and discards whatever was in `m` before, so whatever was stored in `m` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth pointing out that the lines `Object m = new A();` and `m = new Object();` could be written in a longer form as

```
Object m;
m = new A();
m = new Object();
```

where it is more visible that `m` itself exists without an object reference being stored in it already. So it just "happens" that the next line puts an `A` reference into it, but `m` itself refers to an `Object`, as its declaration states.

---

It would be very different if you used the `var` keyword (relatively new thing, available from Java 10), where the compiler deducts a fitting type for the right side of the initialization (and thus `var`s have to be initialized immediately):

```
var m = new A();
m = new Object();
```

this will die, not in runtime, but in compliation time already. The first line implicitly becomes `A m = new A();`, and thus `m = new Object();` doesn't make sense anymore.